# How to store which div is clicked on in php?

Tags: php

I have a bunch of divs that light up when they are clicked on (but only one div can be clicked on). I want to find out which div is clicked on when a user presses a "submit" button using PHP although I'm not sure this can be done.

This is the code I have for the click:

```
<script>
   $( function() {
$('.column').click( function() {
$('.column').css('background-color',"");
$(this).css('background-color', '#A3C2C2');
  } );
} );
   </script>
```

then I have the divs:

```
<div class="column" onclick="function()" style="background-color: rgb(163, 194, 194);">
<p>Burgers</p>
<div class="avatar">
<img src="img/burgers.ico" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div></div>

<div class="column" onclick="function()" style="background-color: rgb(163, 194, 194);">
<p> Tacoes</p><div class="avatar">
<img src="img/taco.ico" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div></div>

<div class="column" onclick="function()" style="background-color: rgb(163, 194, 194);">
<p> Tacoes</p><div class="avatar">
<img src="img/taco.ico" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div></div>
```

The user is only able to click one div - is there any way using PHP to find out which div was clicked on? The reason I want to use php for this instead of javascript is because I want to store this clicked variable to do a query on a mysql table

Comment: You'd have to run an ajax request via jquery when the `click` event fires, and store that "div" id somewhere in a table, which you'd have to associate with a user.

Comment: you could use an ajax call to and pass the clicked div as a parameter to a php script.

Answer (score 0):

Give a meaningful id to your divs:

```
<div id="burger" class="column" onclick="function()" style="background-color: rgb(163, 194, 194);">
```

Extend your script by ajax:

```
<script>
$( function() {
   $('.column').click( function() {
     $('.column').css('background-color',"");
     $(this).css('background-color', '#A3C2C2');
        $.ajax({
           url:'somefile.php',
           type:'post',
           data: { clickeddiv : $(this).attr('id') },
           success : function(e) {
                     alert ('saved'); } // or whatever you want as success, maybe here nothing 

   });
  });
});
</script>
```

and catch the data in somefile.php with:

```
$_POST['clickeddiv']
```

and save it to a table or proccess it however you need to.

Comment: hmm is there a way to do this without ajax?

Comment: Not in the way you are descriping the desired behaviour.